# Python tk ウィジット上の座標を判断したい

Tags: python, tkinter

**実現したいこと**
異なるCanvasウィジット間でドラッグアンドドロップを実現する。

**やろうとしていること**
マウスイベントを親ウィンドウでバインドし、その座標情報からCanvasウィジット上にある座標かを判断し、Canvasウィジット上の座標に変換して、各Canvas内のオブジェクトを操作する。

**現在の問題点・試したこと**
該当するCanvasウィジット内の有効な座標かどうかを判断したく、各Canvasウィジットのメソッドcanvasx,canvasyを取得して判断しようとしました。
eventで対象ウィジットの情報が得られたため、どのウィジットでのイベントかは判断できましたが、マウス移動、マウスリリース時では、その移動先のウィジットの情報が得られません。

Canvasウィジット自体の親ウィンドウ上の座標が分かれば、判断できると思うのですが、座標の取得方法が分かりません。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教示お願い致します。

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_w = 800
        self.screen_h = 300
        self.dlg_pos_x = 10
        self.dlg_pos_y = 10

        return super().__init__()

    def createMainWindow(self):

        self.MainWindow = ttk.tkinter.Tk() 

        geo_string = str(self.screen_w) + "x" + str(self.screen_h) + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_x)  + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_y) 

        self.MainWindow.geometry(geo_string) 

        _InFrame_ = tk.Frame(
            self.MainWindow,
            width = 300,
            height = 200,
            )

        self._Canvas_A_ = tk.Canvas(
            _InFrame_,
            bg = 'red'
            )

        self._Canvas_B_ = tk.Canvas(
            _InFrame_,
            bg = 'blue'
            )
        _InFrame_.pack()
        self._Canvas_A_.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        self._Canvas_B_.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

        self.MainWindow.bind('<Button-1>',self.MainWindow_left_click)
        self.MainWindow.bind('<B1-Motion>',self.MainWindow_drag_mouse_move_on)
        self.MainWindow.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.MainWindow_mouse_release)

        return self.MainWindow

    def MainWindow_left_click(self,event):
        if event.widget == self._Canvas_A_:
            x = self._Canvas_A_.canvasx(event.x)
            y = self._Canvas_A_.canvasx(event.y)
            print('_Canvas_A_(Clicled):',x,y)
        if event.widget == self._Canvas_B_:
            x = self._Canvas_B_.canvasx(event.x)
            y = self._Canvas_B_.canvasx(event.y)
            print('_Canvas_B_(Clicled):',x,y)

        return

    def MainWindow_drag_mouse_move_on(self,event):
        if event.widget == self._Canvas_A_:
            x = self._Canvas_A_.canvasx(event.x)
            y = self._Canvas_A_.canvasx(event.y)
            print('_Canvas_A_(move):',x,y)
        if event.widget == self._Canvas_B_:
            x = self._Canvas_B_.canvasx(event.x)
            y = self._Canvas_B_.canvasx(event.y)
            print('_Canvas_B_(move):',x,y)
        return

    def MainWindow_mouse_release(self,event):
        if event.widget == self._Canvas_A_:
            x = self._Canvas_A_.canvasx(event.x)
            y = self._Canvas_A_.canvasx(event.y)
            print('_Canvas_A_(release):',x,y)
        if event.widget == self._Canvas_B_:
            x = self._Canvas_B_.canvasx(event.x)
            y = self._Canvas_B_.canvasx(event.y)
            print('_Canvas_B_(release):',x,y)
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()
    #testobj = tkTest.CreateScreen()

    MainWindow_obj = screen_obj.createMainWindow()

    #testobj._TemplateDialog(MainWindow_obj)

    MainWindow_obj.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
他にスマートな書き方があれば、回答をお願いします。

Canvasのwinfo_rootx()およびwinfo_rooty()でウィンドウ上の座標が得られます。
さらにCanvasのwidth,heightの情報が得られます。
これらの情報により、各々のCanvasの座標範囲を求め、eventで与えられるウィンドウ上の座標x_root、y_rootが座標範囲に入っているかで判断できました。
これであとは、Canvas内座標により対象のオブジェクトを判断すれば良いようです。

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_w = 800
        self.screen_h = 300
        self.dlg_pos_x = 10
        self.dlg_pos_y = 10

        return super().__init__()

    def createMainWindow(self):

        self.MainWindow = ttk.tkinter.Tk() 

        geo_string = str(self.screen_w) + "x" + str(self.screen_h) + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_x)  + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_y) 

        self.MainWindow.geometry(geo_string) 

        _InFrame_ = tk.Frame(
            self.MainWindow,
            width = 300,
            height = 200,
            )

        self._Canvas_A_ = tk.Canvas(
            _InFrame_,
            bg = 'red'
            )

        self._Canvas_B_ = tk.Canvas(
            _InFrame_,
            bg = 'blue'
            )
        _InFrame_.pack()
        self._Canvas_A_.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        self._Canvas_B_.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

        self.MainWindow.bind('<Button-1>',self.MainWindow_left_click)
        self.MainWindow.bind('<B1-Motion>',self.MainWindow_drag_mouse_move_on)
        self.MainWindow.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.MainWindow_mouse_release)

        return self.MainWindow

    def canvas_coords(self,canvas):
        sx = x = int(canvas.winfo_rootx())
        sy = y = int(canvas.winfo_rooty())
        w = int(canvas['width'])
        h = int(canvas['height'])
        ex = sx + w - 1
        ey = sy + h - 1

        return (sx,sy,ex,ey)

    def chk_canvas_coords(self,canvas,point):
        _canvas_coords = self.canvas_coords(canvas)

        SX = X = 0
        SY = Y = 1
        EX = 2
        EY = 3

        if ((point[X] >=_canvas_coords[SX] and point[X] <=_canvas_coords[EX])
            and (point[Y] >=_canvas_coords[SY] and point[Y] <=_canvas_coords[EY])):
            return True

        return False

    def MainWindow_left_click(self,event):
        x, y = event.x_root, event.y_root
        if self.chk_canvas_coords(self._Canvas_A_,(x,y)):
            print('_Canvas_A_:Left_clicked')
        if self.chk_canvas_coords(self._Canvas_B_,(x,y)):
            print('_Canvas_B_:Left_clicked')

        return

    def MainWindow_drag_mouse_move_on(self,event):
        x, y = event.x_root, event.y_root
        if self.chk_canvas_coords(self._Canvas_A_,(x,y)):
            print('_Canvas_A_:move_on')
        if self.chk_canvas_coords(self._Canvas_B_,(x,y)):
            print('_Canvas_B_:move_on')
        return

    def MainWindow_mouse_release(self,event):
        x, y = event.x_root, event.y_root
        if self.chk_canvas_coords(self._Canvas_A_,(x,y)):
            print('_Canvas_A_:release')
        if self.chk_canvas_coords(self._Canvas_B_,(x,y)):
            print('_Canvas_B_:release')
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()
    #testobj = tkTest.CreateScreen()

    MainWindow_obj = screen_obj.createMainWindow()

    #testobj._TemplateDialog(MainWindow_obj)

    MainWindow_obj.mainloop()
```